# How to get entries between a time

Tags: datetime

I'm using Craft 3 and I would like to do the following thing:

There is a start date and an end date filed in entry, is it possible to get entries that are between these two dates in PHP?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Entry::find()->startDate('>='. $someTime).endTime('<='.$someOtherTime).all();
```

Those variables can be timestamps, DateTimes or a correctly formated time string.

Here are some variants of these filters

```
Entry::find()
    ->variantOne('<=' .  Db::prepareDateForDb(new \DateTime())) <-- DateTime object
    ->variantTwo('<=' . time())  <-- as timestamp
    ->variantThree('<=' . (new \DateTime())->format('U')) <-- timestamp as well
    ->variant(['and', '<=' . time() , '>=' . time() - 3600]) <-- entries within the last hour
    ->validString(['or', '>=' . (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), '<= ' . time()])
```

Comment: I tried `$entites = Entry::find()->startDate('>='. (new \DateTime('now'))->format('m/d/Y') )->all();`, but got an database error like `SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""`

Comment: @yuxia I've added a few examples

Comment: Works just like magic!!! Many many thanks:)

Comment: I had the same problem the other day and solved it like this
`{% set params = {
  section : 'theSection',
  startDate : '>=' ~ someTime,
  endDate : '<=' ~ someOtherTime,
} %}
{% set entries = craft.entries(params).all() %}`
Are there benefits to `Entry::find()` over `craft.entries(params)`?

Comment: @JohannDyck `Entry::find` is PHP Syntax, `craft.entries` is twig syntax that executes `Entry::find()` You can see what `craft.entries` does here https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/web/twig/variables/CraftVariable.php#L262