# ANDing criteria in craft.entries

Tags: craft.entries

This works:

```
            {% set entries = craft.entries({
                section: 'listing',
                listinglatitudenumber: '>=' ~ pluginResults.latmin
            }) %}
```

But I need to do this:

```
            {% set entries = craft.entries({
                section: 'listing',
                listinglatitudenumber: 'and', '>=' ~ pluginResults.latmin, '<=' ~ pluginResults.latmax
            }) %}
```

And I cannot for the life of me figure out the correct syntax for this.

I have been trying many different combos for the 'and' statement based on other answers I have seen in the Craft Stack Exchange but have not been successful. I have not been able to find any docs on this type of query.

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per:
[Query entries between two values](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22593/query-entries-between-two-values?rq=1)
I found that enclosing the query string that I had with [ ] to make it a sub-array, works:

```
        {% set entries = craft.entries({
            section: 'listing',
            listinglatitudenumber: ['and', '>=' ~ pluginResults.latmin, '<=' ~ pluginResults.latmax]
        }) %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate your criterias with commas

```
listinglatitudenumber: 'and, ' ~  '>=' ~ pluginResults.latmin ~ ', <=' ~ pluginResults.latmin,
```

Comment: Thanks Robin once again for your help :)
With the above syntax I get:


Internal Server Error

A hash value must be followed by a comma. Unexpected token "string" of value ", <=" ("punctuation" expected with value ",").

And I am trying to understand exactly what you mean, and trying to resolve the error, but not successful - could you explain further?

Comment: Of course you need to place a last comma since you are inside an object. Please read this https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/25774/5557 you can either separate your values via comma or you use an array from the beginning

Comment: Thank you I will look at the examples and try to get it working :)

Comment: Let me know if you need further help. You simply need to convert PHP string separators `.` with twig `~`

Comment: Thank you Robin again for your time and effort on this. :)

Comment: Hi Robin, At the time you provided your answer using commas, I was not able to get that to work and so I found another way to do it using [ ]. I now see that using commas would also work - I did not mean to diminish your answer. Thanks again.